# Toggleable word wrap for java.awt.textarea

Tags: java, swing, textarea, awt

I need to add the ability for the user to toggle word wrap on the AWT Component TextArea. I've a couple of ways, but none of them seem to allow for the ability for me to allow a method to tell the textarea to toggle/untoggle word wrap. Is there a method that TextArea has? Thanks.

Comment: swing tag is for something?

Comment: I'm using the Swing Window builder for Eclipse

Comment: and why you are not using `javax.swing.JTextArea` ?

Comment: Why AWT rather than Swing?  See this answer on [Swing extras over AWT](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6255978/418556) for many good reasons to abandon using AWT components.  If you need to support older AWT based APIs, see [Mixing Heavyweight and Lightweight Components](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/mixing-components-433992.html).

Answer (score 0):

Use the javax.swing.JTextArea instead of the AWT Component. It has the method setLineWrap();.